# why my ajaxstart and ajaxstop with error function not working?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

My ajaxStart and AjaxStop function might not be firing.
This is what i tried:

```
<body>
<div id="loading">
    <img src="loading.gif" alt="" width="100px" height="100px">
</div>
<div id="divResult"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        var $loading = $('#loading').hide()
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $($loading).show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $($loading).hide()
            alert('All ajax requests completed')
        });
        $(document).ajaxError(function (thrownError) {
            if (thrownError === 'timeout') {
                alert('timeout')
            };
        })
    })

</script>
</body>
```

Hopefully i could get some help.
Thanks already!

Comment: What does `jquery-easing` have to do with this?

Comment: The `ajaxStart` event happens when you make the first AJAX request. Your script doesn't have any AJAX requests.

Comment: You don't need to write `$($loading)`. Just use `$loading`.